# storing image path for specific record not for all records?

Tags: ms-access-2010

i have this code

```
Private Sub cmdBrowse_Click()
Dim FileOpenDialog As FileDialog
Set FileOpenDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
Dim SelectedFile As Variant
Dim db As DAO.Database
Set db = CurrentDb
With FileOpenDialog
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    .Title = "Select A File To Use As A Logo"
    .Filters.Clear
    .Filters.Add "Images", "*.gif; *.jpg; *.jpeg;*.bmp;*.png"
    .ButtonName = "Use This File"
   If .Show = True Then
      For Each SelectedFile In .SelectedItems
        Dim LogoFile As String
        LogoFile = SelectedFile
        Dim barewabarayate As Recordset
        Set barewabarayate = db.OpenRecordset("barewabarayate")
        With barewabarayate
            .Edit
            barewabarayate.Fields("image_path") = LogoFile
            barewabarayate.Update
          End With
        Next
    End If
    End With
End Sub
```

When I click cmdbrowse button for opening an image it work success and display the selected image in my image control also it store the image path in my table field ... my problem is when click next button on my form for changing record it display the image with every record in my table i want my code stores image path for only one record not all records?

Comment: Please use the code button - {} to format your posts.

Comment: What is the `Control Source` of your Image control?

Comment: Gord Thompson , a table field that store image path  ("image_path")